# How does Facebook put this formatted text in JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, facebook, console

[image]

By opening JavaScript console on Facebook it warns you not to put anything there, to be safe from scam. This seems a very good counter measure against "make your victim do the work for you" attacks. How do they do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

console.log() can be formatted with inline CSS

**This:**

```
console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");
```

**Will look like this:**
[image]

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#styling-console-output-with-css)